# Autofac Resolve Non-Singleton Objects In Singleton Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

My application structure is as follows:

Web server using Web Api Http requests receieved from clients, Getting to AppCoreLayer (Singleton) and from there it is sent to the DAL which uses EF code first.

Moreover, a Tcp connection is established between the logic layer and an external application.

In my DAL I use a DbContext which I register within my DI container (Autofac) as PerRequest.

My issue here is that I will soon receive messages from the external application and will need to execute some db operations, but I can't manage to understand how a DbContext will be instantiated this way.

I've read that register the objects PerMatchingLifetimeScope helps with external applications that don't support Requests, yet I don't understand if and how will that help me her. Would love an explaination.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In default relationship AppCoreLayer needs DbContext. But in your situation AppCoreLayer  needs to create DbContext. You can do this easily with using [Dynamic Instantiation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/stable/resolve/relationships.html#dynamic-instantiation-func-b).

> Using an auto-generated factory can let you effectively call
>   Resolve() without tying your component to Autofac. Use this
>   relationship type if you need to create more than one instance of a
>   given service, or if you’re not sure if you’re going to need a service
>   and want to make the decision at runtime.

But if your `DbContext` registered as `InstancePerRequest` you should resolve DbContext by yourself. Because singleton objects are resolved in root lifetime scope but per request has different lifetimescope.

So you can use `ILifeTimeScope` or `DependencyResolver` to resolve `DbContext`. Here is an example:

```
        public Func<T> HttpRequestScopedFactoryFor<T>()
        {
            return () => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<T>();
        }

        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType(typeof(DerivedDbContext)).AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterInstance(HttpRequestScopedFactoryFor<DerivedDbContext>());
        }
```

Also check [this](https://robdmoore.id.au/blog/2013/03/23/resolving-request-scoped-objects-into-a-singleton-with-autofac/).

Comment: I have an issue that my logic layer must be singleton,

Comment: Then you can't use. Because, logic layer dependent objects should be singleton also. You should use `InstancePerLifetimeScope` it's wider than per request scope. So that's mean if dbcontext is created by request it is disposed with request. But if it's created by singleton object it will be singleton also and lives with this object (Your Logic Layer). And if your dbcontext is just depented with your logic layer you can make it singleinstance also.

Comment: But single instance of dbContext is bad practice from what I have heard. Than all of my application sort of has to be singleton.. If I register LogicLayer as PerScope, will it be instantiated again for every request?

Comment: Yes you are right you shouldn't use. So I understand now your question. I have edited your question and my answer also.